# Angular and Karma - Why does this test fail?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I'm working on the [Angular Phonecat tutorial](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/docs/tutorial), and incorporating some of the suggestions in [Opinionated AngularJS Styleguide](http://toddmotto.com/opinionated-angular-js-styleguide-for-teams/)

However, I'm having a hard time understanding why a specific Karma test is failing.

My application code is:

```
function routeProvider(provider){ ... }

function phoneListCtrl(scope, http){ ... }

function phoneDetailCtrl(scope, http, routeParams){
    http.get("/phones/" + routeParams.phoneId + ".json").success(function(data){
        scope.phone = data;
    });
}

angular.module("phonecatApp", ["ngRoute"])
    .controller('PhoneListCtrl', ["$scope", "$http",  function($scope, $http){
         phoneListCtrl($scope, $http);
    }])
    .controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', function($scope,     $routeParams, $http){
        phoneDetailCtrl($scope, $http, $routeParams);
    }])
    .config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
        routeProvider($routeProvider);
    }]);
```

This application code works in the browser, where both phone list and phone detail views show as expected.  No errors are reported in the console.

However, this test for PhoneDetailCtrl fails due to

```
PhoneCat Controllers PhoneDetailCtrl should fetch phone detail FAILED
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeParamsProvider <- $routeParams

describe("PhoneDetailCtrl", function(){
    var scope, $httpBackend, ctrl;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $routeParams, $controller){
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $httpBackend.expectGET("phones/xyz.json").respond({name : "phone xyz"});

        $routeParams.phoneId = "xyz";
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller("PhoneDetailCtrl", {$scope : scope});
    }));

    it("should fetch phone detail", function(){
        expect(scope.phone).toBeUndefined();
        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect(scope.phone).toEqual({name : "phone xyz"});
    });
});
```

Specifically, the `beforeEach(inject(function( ... ) { ... }));` is throwing the error prior before going to code in `angular-mocks.js`.

Why is the test code failing only after reorganizing the application code, yet still works in the browser?  This only occurs when running Karma tests, all Protractor tests pass.

**ETA**

Some people have asked about the `files` array in `karma.conf.js`.  The settings are:

```
files : [
  'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/js/**/*.js',
  'test/unit/**/*.js'
],
```

Comment: Has `karma.conf.js` or similar file in section files path to angular-resource.js file?

Comment: Don't you mean `angular-route.js`?

Comment: Can you describe what you changed when you reorganized the application code that caused the test to fail? That's probably a good clue...

Comment: Yes, angular-route was in my mind, now, please show `app.js` – first lines where you describe dependencies - Do you have something like `angular.module('youApplicationName', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute','ngSanitize'])`?

Comment: What you see in my app code is what is in app.js. the only current dependency is `ngRoute`

Answer (score 4):

I had similar error in exactly the same test. I figured out that problem was in the fact that module was defined inside one of the internal `describe` blocks. Moving module creation statement to the top level `describe` block fixed this error.

Here's erroneous code:

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {

    describe('PhoneListCtrl', function() {
        var scope, ctrl, $httpBackend;

        beforeEach(module('phonecatApp'));
        ...
    });

    describe('PhoneDetailCtrl', function() {
        var scope, $httpBackend, ctrl;
        ...
    });
```

Correct should be:

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {

    beforeEach(module('phonecatApp'));

    describe('PhoneListCtrl', function() {
        var scope, ctrl, $httpBackend;
        ...
    });

    describe('PhoneDetailCtrl', function() {
        var scope, $httpBackend, ctrl;
        ...
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are missing reference to `bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js`
in your `karma.conf.js` .. check this file or any other entity you use for testing that it has angular-route DI

Comment: See my edit, I added the files array in `karma.conf.js`.  `angular-route.js` is already included.  If I comment it out, all four tests fail, rather than just the one.